Buscar un valor en toda la base de datos MySQL
Recientemente, realicé la migración de mi sitio WordPress a un nuevo hosting. Durante el proceso, algo salió mal y algunas URLs de imágenes o CSS aún apuntan al dominio anterior, lo que provoca que no se carguen correctamente. Me tomé la tarea de buscar masivamente en todos los archivos donde apareciera el string del dominio anterior y lo reemplacé por el nuevo. Sin embargo, aún siguen apareciendo recursos (imágenes adjuntas, portadas, css, etc.) con el dominio anterior, lo que me lleva a deducir que el string del dominio anterior podría encontrarse en la base de datos.
El problema que enfrento es que no puedo realizar una instalación nueva, no tengo respaldos disponibles y buscar manualmente en todas las tablas el string es extremadamente tedioso debido a la gran cantidad de tablas (más de 230).
Por lo tanto, solicito su ayuda para realizar lo siguiente:
Necesito buscar un string en todos los campos de todas las tablas de la base de datos en MySQL y que el resultado sea el nombre de las tablas donde se encuentra el string. No es necesario que se indique la columna, con conocer el nombre de la tabla ya me ayudaría significativamente a reducir la cantidad de tablas a revisar.
Agradezco de antemano.
Ya busqué en otras preguntas como esta Buscar Valor un valor en todas las tablas de base de datos y el ejecutar tanto el script de la pregunta como de la respuesta obtengo este  error:
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare @src varchar(128) = 'greenyellow-turtle'
set nocount on
declare @sql varchar(5...' at line 2

Error position: line: 1


Pero no has pasado el codigo que dice que esta mal el error.

Dado que enlazas la pregunta, dónde es obvio que el código no era correcto, me pregunto si estás usando el código de la respuesta que recibió dicha pregunta. También, en caso que sea afirmativo, creo que vendría bien saber cuál es la versión de base de datos sobre la que quieres ejecutarlo.

¿y porque no usas el plugin de wordpress para eso?  Se llama better-search-replace y te ahorrarás una burrada de trabajo, especialmente cuando el string aparece en campos serializados. Otra forma de buscar en todas las tablas es usando el phpmyadmin que te escribe la query por ti.  Ojo al usarlo, no te equivoques de string, pues los cambios pueden ser irreversibles. Haz backup de la base de datos antes.

Excorpion alli puse el error que obtengo. jachguate, tambien ejecute la respuesta de abajo y da error. masterguru, voy a probar con ese pugin. A todos muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

El problema no se resolverá con un buscar / reemplazar si los campos están serializados, debes usar las herramientas adecuadas, que podrían ser plugins como Better Search Replace o mediante WP-Cli (te recomendaría mejor esta opción), que tiene un comando para buscar / reemplazar mira los ejemplos en el enlace. Sea como sea, no conviene tener el dominio escrito a mano en el contenido de tu Wordpress, si tal es el caso, aprovecha para corregir esa anomalía.

@A.Cedano con el better-search-replace que recomendaron en otro comentario, pude solucionar el problema. Muchas gracias a todos.

Creo que lo que quieres hacer se soluciona haciendo un SELECT: select * from tus_tablas_separadas_por_comas where='el string que estás buscando'; , una vez hayas encontrado los registros que necesitas, reemplaza el valor de dichos campos con la sentencia UPDATE: update * from tus_tablas set nombre_del_campo_separado_por_comas where='nuevo valor a ingresar';
o en su defecto te recomiendo que leas la respuesta a esta preguntaBuscar un registro en toda la base de datos
Espero que mi respuesta te sea útil.
PD: Cuando hagas preguntas en stack overflow tanto en español, como en inglés, ve al grano, porque te pueden cerrar la pregunta directamente los moderadores/bots o la misma comunidad, con esto quiero decir a que solo pongas el problema que tienes o la duda que tienes al respecto sin dar más "choro" por así decirlo.
Osea que la explicación del porque hiciste la migración es algo irrelevante, solo pon el problema que presentas y ya.

Cuando respondas a una pregunta, asegúrate de que respondes a lo que se pregunta! Está buscando la manera de saber en qué tablas existe un determinado valor, no quiere escribir el nombre de sus 240 tablas para hacer un select.

@Emmanuelito18, muchas gracias por tu respuesta y tu sugerencia, la tendré en cuenta para una próxima pregunta. Solo que vi relevante poner lo demás, ya que posiblemente a alguien le haya sucedido lo mismo y pudo resolverlo, también se abre la pregunta a responder al problema inicial y no al final. Fíjate en el comentario que dejaron en otra respuesta, ese plug-in me sirvió.

yo entendí que el chico quiere buscar una gran cantidad de registros que corresponden con un dato en concreto . pero tomo nota para corregir mi respuesta más tarde
